# How to Fix WordPress Not Saving Settings?

Tags: wp-admin, options, language, bug, customization

### How Can I Manually Fix & What is The Root Cause?

The `Site Language` setting in `Settings > General` for [my site](https://lbryhub.com), will not update.

It is stuck on `English (United States)`.

I have done all the usually debugging procedures, such as disabling all my plugins etc, reinstalling WordPress etc. But the issue remains.

---

**Q:** What is the best way to manually fix this, and what is the root cause of the issue likely to be?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

A possible source to the problem is the Divi theme, which applies its own translation settings. Try to go to Divi → Theme Options → General → Disable Translations and make sure that they are disabled and then recheck.

**Workaround**

Another way to fix this problem is by adding this snippet to your `functions.php` file:

```
function setLocale($locale) {
    return ‘LANGUAGE CODE’;
}
add_filter(‘locale’, ‘setLocale’);
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and in my case the reason why it didn't work was that:

- I use Divi
- in functions.php Divi has function et_divi_maybe_change_frontend_locale and it returns 'en_US' by default.

Just change 'en_US' to your language.
Remember to use a child theme if you're modyfying functions.php

Comment: I have multiple Divi sites. It only happens to one. In functions.php there's only the following code which contains `en_US`, which is the same even when English UK is correctly set on other sites and if I change it manually, it makes no difference. if ( 'on' === $disable_translations ) {
  return 'en_US';
 }

Comment: I'm unable to tell you the exact problem but you can change that settings from the option table in the DB.